# Looking for free productivity software for non-profit operations

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a productivity/operations management web service (ideally, free) that is aimed towards non-profits. Some of the features that I'm looking for include:

- Indexing and sorting of contacts
- Organizing milestones into a tree hierarchy
- Tagging of documents for indexing and searching

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i take your question correctly, you are asking for a groupware function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_groupware

Wikipedia lists a few of the groupware projects here. Opengroupware.org provides a full-functioning suite in relatively stable state. You can check it out.

If you do not mind using two software, then a simple communication suite + a content management software can also allow you to work easily. (KnowledgeTree [community edition, which is free] can be used for the knowledge management.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnuenterprise.org/packages/

This website here might be of use to you.